# Problemas al consultar Local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Muy Buenas tengo un inconveniente al tratar de recorrer el local storage para asignar clases y estilos a elementos en el DOM. El caso es que se envía una petición ajax que devuelve una carga al local storage he usado setTimeout para esperar que el localstorage cargue, pero en local funciona sin problemas pero ya la cosa es un poco más demorada en servidor de pruebas, quiero saber si existe un método js que se active o algo parecido para saber si ya puedo consultar el localstorage. esto es lo que hago para consultarlo.

```
function addToCartProductInd(sku) {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')) != null) {
        var Lstorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage'));
        if (Lstorage.cart && Lstorage.cart.items != null) {
            var Prod_Larecetta = Lstorage.cart.items;
            $.each( Prod_Larecetta, function( key, value ) {
                if(value.product_sku == sku){
                    $("#remove-itm-in-cart-"+sku).attr('data-item-to-remove',value.item_id);
                    $("#input-number-"+sku).val(value.qty).attr('data-item_id',value.item_id);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías leer el localStorage en otra función y asignar el valor a una variable global (x), luego dentro de la función addToCartProductInd(sku) comprobar si el valor de la variable global x es distinto a null/false etc. Si sigue siendo null vuelves a llamar a 
addToCartProductInd(sku).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero es importante leer [answer] .